# To find the particular integral of second order ode with nonconstant coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> What is the particular integral $y_{p}$ of the differential equation $$x^2y''+xy'-y=\dfrac{1}{x+1}$$

Putting $x=e^t$ we get $(D^2 -1)y(t)= \dfrac{1}{e^t+1}$

therefore $y_{p}= \{ \dfrac{1}{D^2 -1} \} \dfrac{1}{e^t+1}$

$=- \big( 1+D^2+D^4+...\big)  \dfrac{1}{e^t+1}$

$= - {  \dfrac{1}{e^t+1} +\dfrac{2!}{ (e^t+1)^2}+\dfrac{4!}{ (e^t+1)^4}+....}$

I am stuck here. What could be the next step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$y_{p}=  \dfrac{1}{D^2 -1}  \dfrac{1}{e^t+1}$

$=\frac{1}{2}\Biggr(\frac{1}{D-1}-\frac{1}{D+1}\Biggr) \dfrac{1}{e^t+1}$

$=\frac{1}{2} \Biggr\{\frac{1}{D-1}\dfrac{1}{e^t+1}- \frac{1}{D+1}\dfrac{1}{e^t+1}\Biggr\}$

$=\frac{1}{2} \Biggr\{e^{t}\int \dfrac{e^{-t}}{e^t+1}dt-e^{-t}\int\dfrac{e^{t}}{e^t+1}dt\Biggr\}$ $\qquad. . . . .(1) $

Now $$\int\dfrac{e^{t}}{e^t+1}dt=\log(e^t+1)$$

and $$\int\dfrac{e^{-t}}{e^t+1}dt=\int\frac{1}{u(u-1)^2}du=\int  \Biggr(\frac{1}{u}-\frac{1}{u-1}+\frac{1}{(u-1)^2} \Biggr)du=\log u-\log(u-1) -\frac{1}{u-1}= \log (e^t+1)-t-{e^{-t}}$$

[in the second integral putting $e^t+1=u \implies e^t dt = du \quad \text{and } \quad e^{-t}=\frac{1}{u-1}$]

From $(1)$, $$y_p=\frac{1}{2} \Biggr\{ e^t(\log (e^t+1)-t-{e^{-t}})  -e^{-t} \log(e^t+1)\Biggr\}$$
$$y_p=\frac{1}{2} \Biggr\{ x(\log (x+1)-\log x-{\frac{1}{x}})  -\frac{1}{x} \log(x+1)\Biggr\}$$
$$y_p=\frac{1}{2} \Biggr\{ \log(x+1) (x-\frac{1}{x})-{x}{\log x}-1 \Biggr\}$$

---

For the Particular Integral (i.e., P.I.) there are some general rules

> $1.$ $\frac{1}{D + a} \phi (x) = e^{-ax}\int e^{ax}\phi(x)$
>
> $2.$ $\frac{1}{f(D)} e^{ax} \phi(x) = e^{ax}\frac{1}{f(D+a)} \phi(x)$
>
> $3.$ $\frac{1}{f(D)} x^{n} \sin ax  = $Imaginary part of $e^{iax}\frac{1}{f(D+ia)} x^n$
>
> $4.$ $\frac{1}{f(D)} x^{n} \cos ax  = $Real part of $e^{iax}\frac{1}{f(D+ia)} x^n$
>
> $5.$ $\frac{1}{f(D)} x^{n} (\cos ax + i\sin ax)  = \frac{1}{f(D)} x^n e^{iax}=e^{iax}\frac{1}{f(D+ia)} x^n$

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do it this way. Just write $$\frac{1}{D^2-1} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{D-1} - \frac{1}{D+1}\right)$$
Now, $\frac{1}{D-1}\frac{1}{e^t+1}$ is just $$e^t \int \frac{e^{-t}}{e^t+1}$$ (and similarly for the 2nd term)

Thus, we can get $y_p$.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the problem simpler if you start with $y=z\, x$ to get
$$x^3 z''+3 x^2 z'=\frac{1}{x+1}\implies \big(x^3z'\big)'=\frac{1}{x+1}\implies x^3z'=\log(x+1)+C$$

Answer (score 1):

Your equation is Euler-Cauchy with basis solutions $x,x^{-1}$. As the right side is not in the class suitable for the method of unknown coefficients, you need to go via variation of constants.
\begin{align}
y(x)&=c_1(x)x+c_2(x)x^{-1},\\
xy'(x)&=c_1(x)x-c_2(x)x^{-1}~~\text{demanding}~~ c_1'(x)x+c_2'(x)x^{-1}=0,\\
x(xy'(x))'&=y(x)+c_1'(x)x^2-c_2'(x)\implies c_1'(x)x^2-c_2'(x)=\frac1{1+x}.
\end{align}
Solving for $c_1',c_2'$ gives 
\begin{align}
2c_1'(x)&=\frac1{x^2(1+x)}=\frac1{x^2}-\frac1{x(x+1)}
\\
&=\frac1{x^2}-\frac1x+\frac1{1+x}\\
2c_2'(x)&=-\frac1{1+x}
\end{align}

This gives as solution on $x>0$
$$
y(x)=\frac12\left(\ln(1+x)(x-x^{-1})-x\ln x-1\right)+C_1x+C_2x^{-1}
$$

Answer (score 1):

With your method 
$$
\begin{align}
\dfrac{1}{D^2-1}\dfrac{e^{-t}}{1+e^{-t}}
&= \dfrac{1}{D^2-1}\left(e^{-t}-\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}e^{-nt}\right)\\
&= \dfrac{-t}{2}e^{-t}- \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{D^2-1}e^{-nt}\\
&= \dfrac{-t}{2}e^{-t}- \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^n}{n^2-1}e^{-nt}
\end{align}
$$